# C# WPF Load ComboBox from txt file similar to Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listbox that I am populating from a text file with this code..

(Works)

```
private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
Listbox1.ItemsSource = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\servers.txt");
}
```

But when i try to populate a Combobox dropdown list the same way.. the list is empty.

(Doesnt work.. is blank combobox)

```
private void ComboBox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
ComboBox2.ItemsSource = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\servers.txt");
}
```

thanks!

Comment: That's a SelectionChanged handler on the initially empty ComboBox2? How is it supposed to be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the value for the ComboBox in the Selection_Changed event handler. The code in this block will only fire if someone changes the selected value in the combo box - which will never happen because there isn't anything in it - hence your code isn't being run. You should put that code in the constructor  for the page, or an OnNavigatedTo() method.

```
public YourPageName()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ComboBox2.ItemsSource = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\servers.txt");
    }
```